# What is the default enum value in proto2 given reserved field tags?

Tags: enums, protocol-buffers

Let's say you have the following enum in proto2.

```
  enum my_enum {
    reserved 0;
    VALUE = 1; 
    ANOTHER = 2;
  }
```

My question is... what is the default enum value in this case where there is no default defined? In the docs it says,

> For enums, the default value is the first value listed in the enum's type definition.

... so does "first value" mean `0` (reserved) or `1`?

Comment: This is a great question! Note that once parsed, the fact that the line `reserved 0` was first in the schema **is not retained** - the enums and reservations are stored separately, so I *expect* the answer is `VALUE = 1`, however: frankly, it is a really really good idea to add a dummy value with value `0`, to allow for future proto3 compatibility and just to keep things simple. Slight confession: I've never actually seen reserved fields used in enums, and I've processed every schema I could find, to prove my custom DSL parser. It turns out my custom parser doesn't handle this case yet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested this in my code with

```
message my_enum {
    enum my_service {
        reserved 0;
        VALUE = 1;
    }
    optional my_service selected_service = 1;
}
```

and it defaulted to `VALUE` (i.e. 1) not 0.